# Add a mean to a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I want something similar to my example but replacing the line by a point in black color. Is it possible? The documentation does not mention this.

Data & example :

```
library(plotly)

set.seed(1234)
plot_ly(x = ~mean(rnorm(50)), y=c(-2,2), type='scatter', mode='lines') %>% 
  add_boxplot(x = ~rnorm(50), inherit = F) %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(range = c(-2, 2)))
```

I want something similar to this in *ggplot2* :

```
stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the following?

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(1234)
plot_ly(x = ~mean(rnorm(50)), y=c(-2,2), line = list(color = 'black'), type='scatter', mode='lines') %>% 
  add_boxplot(x = ~rnorm(50), inherit = F) %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(range = c(-2, 2)))
```

However I'm not sure what you mean by replacing the line by a point in black color. Do you mean you want two points, with the same x values, but at -2 and +2 on the y scale? If so, why?

Comment: Have you tried creating the desired figure in ggplot, then passing to ggplotly?

Comment: yes it's work but I want to do it directly with plotly